# get username, and id from facebook using php api

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

There is a commenting system in my php application. If user already logined in facebook then I have to hide Name section in my add comment form, If not it need to show Name and comment fields.

Also for displaying comments I need to show user's facebook name and profile thumb.

I tried a lot in developer.facebook site.

Please help me.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the [facebook php-sdk](https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk), you can get the logged-in user's info with this code:

```
$user = $facebook->api('/me');
```

giving of course if the user authorized your application.
You can also display the user's profile picture with:

```
<img src="http://graph.facebook.com/<?php echo $facebook->getUser(); ?>/image" />
```

or you can just use the facebook comments plugin: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/

Comment: can we get the user id of user with this script ?

Comment: $facebook->getUser() return the users facebook id

Comment: any application id and secret code needed for this purpose ? Thanks for your reply

Comment: Yes you need to instantiate the $facebook variable like this: $facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => 'YOUR_APP_ID',
  'secret' => 'YOUR_APP_SECRET',
));

Have a look at the php-sdk documentation to see some examples of implementing it

Comment: I tried the following code ... But its showing "0" all times .. Please help

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
require_once('../src/facebook.php');

$fb_app_id = "id";
$fb_secret = "key";
$fb_app_url = "url";
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => $fb_app_id,
    'secret' => $fb_secret,
    'cookie' => true,
));

$facebook_login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
    'canvas' => 1,
    'fbconnect' => 0,
    'scope' => 'publish_stream,user_photos',
    'redirect_uri' => $fb_app_url
));

echo $facebook_user_id = $facebook->getUser();




?>
```